# What is this "　" called?

Tags: html, utf-8, ansi, nonblank

I am trying to parse a website, and I am trying to replace all occurrence of "　" in a string. This doesn't seem to be space or tab, what is this?

a more general question: how do you search for the name of some char you don't know? I tried [ansi](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html) and [utf-8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm) page with not result.

Comment: looks like a whitespace?

Comment: Also try to highlight that part, maybe there is symbol might show?

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm

Comment: @Niang Looks like a white space but doesn't quack like a white space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is character code 12288, a/k/a an ideographic space for use in, for example, many Asian languages. You can check this with this code:

```
alert( "　".charCodeAt(0) );
```

[More info here.](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm)

**Edit:** You can match this with the regex `\s`. For example, this converts all of those characters to a single, regular space (character 32):

```
"foo　bar　baz".replace(/\s/g, ' '); // produces foo bar baz
```

To replace this character but leave alone "normal" spaces (character 32, tab, new line, carriage return), you might try this:

```
"foo　bar　baz\tblah\tblah\nblah".replace(/(?![ \t\r\n])\s/g, ' ')
```

Comment: Thanks for a way to replicate retrieving the character code.

Comment: Thanks, any advice on how to remove it from a string? `'　'.replace(/'　'/g, "")` doesn't seem to work

Comment: @muyueh Rem0ve the qu0tes fr0m the regex.

Comment: @muyueh See my edit. As Xero said, you don't need quotes in the regex.

Answer (score 3):

That's an ideographic space. Read more about it here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm.